# How can I derive commutation of conjunction: (A or B) = (B or A) using sentential logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Using only introduction and elimination of conjunctions, disjunctions, conditionals, biconditionals, and negations, as well as reiteration (The system "SD" from Bergmann's The Logic Book), how can I obtain B ∨ A, starting with A ∨ B?

EDIT: It's funny, I almost found a derivation but it requires me to substitute A ∨ B with B ∨ A...

SECONDEDIT: I am a fool. Disjunction introduction is defined in SD as
P => P ∨ Q
and
P => Q ∨ P

I suppose I'll leave this here in case someone makes the same mistake. To be fair, there is an exercise in Bergmann's Logic 6th Ed. which asks you to show the equivalence of the two. I assumed I could do it by derivation.

Comment: Begin by looking at the three rules of inference relating to elimination and introduction of disjunction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have to use negation elimination on the negation of the desired result. I don't believe there is a way to eliminate the disjunction and isolate A or B.

Comment: Never mind. Thank you Graham.

Comment: You can post your own solution and accept it.  @LukeRybuck

Comment: "or" is *disjunction*.

Comment: Reasoning backward, in order to derive $(A \lor B) \equiv (B \lor A)$ we need Biconditional introduction, and thus we need two subproofs: one for $(A \lor B) \to (B \lor A)$ and one for $(B \lor A) \to (A \lor B)$

Comment: The two are symmetric; thus it is enough to sketch the first one: apply Disjunction Elim to $(A \lor B)$ deriving $(B \lor A)$ in both sub-proofs using Disjunction Intro. That's all

Answer (score -1):

Since you are working in the empty language, you can make the truth table for both sentences and check that they are the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I have an assignment with a derivation in which using SD alone I must get B ∨ A from A ∨ B. This is just one section of the derivation. It is very obnoxious.